# Date Format Lost When Combining Two Cells Using "&" and CONCATENATE in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, date, concatenate

I'm trying to figure out "how to" maintain the date format when I concatenate a date formatted cell with a nondate formatted cell.

**Result: The Date Format Is Lost**

[image: initial attempt]

**Formulas Used**

[image: formulas used]

**Desired Result: I had to convert Date format to Text Only**

[image: desired result]

I'm trying to figure out "how to" maintain the Date Format while combining two cell values. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the formatting on the fly:

```
=text(B2,"m/d/yyyy")&C2
```

---

Google Sheets Help: [TEXT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139)